# What would 'passwd root --stdin' have set my password to?

Tags: linux, bash, centos, passwd

I ran:

`sshpass -p 'OldPassword' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@1.1.1.1 'echo "Te3EQeF2U!-Em_C3eBU6A&a=u2$e28*c" | passwd root --stdin'`

Without realizing that `echo "Te3EQeF2U!-Em_C3eBU6A&a=u2$e28*c"` results in `bash: !-Em_C3eBU6A: event not found` due to special characters in my password.

Based on this, can anyone work out what it might have set my password to?

Comment: I assume you have tried `bash: !-Em_C3eBU6A: event not found`?

Comment: Yeah, no joy unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try `Te3EQeF2U!-Em_C3eBU6A&a=u2*c`? That worked for me when replicating in a VM.

For reference this is what I did.

On CentOS VM:

```
$ mv /usr/bin/passwd /usr/bin/passwd.orig
$ vim /usr/bin/passwd
<INSERT>
while read line
do
  echo "$line" >> /tmp/passwd
done < /dev/stdin
<SAVE>
```

That will replace the `passwd` binary with one that takes the same input as `passwd --stdin` and simply writes it to `/tmp/passwd`.

Then when I ran `sshpass -p '<VM-PASSWORD>' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@<VM-IP> 'echo "Te3EQeF2U!-Em_C3eBU6A&a=u2$e28*c" | passwd root --stdin'` I got `Te3EQeF2U!-Em_C3eBU6A&a=u2*c` in `/tmp/passwd`

Once you're done just move the original `passwd` binary back.

Comment: damn, I was just about to say that :).  The "!" isn't a problem for non-interactive shells, but the "$e28" is.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `echo 'root:password' | chpasswd` (or `... | chpasswd -e` if the password is already encrypted)?  That's what `chpasswd` is for.  See `man chpasswd` for details and other options.

You also need to quote and/or the password string properly.  You certainly don't want it in double-quotes because it contains `$e28` (which will be expanded to the value of variable `$e28`, which is probably empty).

So, you need to either escape the `$` as `\$`, or you need to single-quote the entire password string.  This is slightly difficult because the `ssh` command is already in single-quotes.  Fortunately, there is a standard and reliable way of embedding single quotes inside single quotes, use `'\''`.

```
sshpass -p 'OldPassword' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
    root@1.1.1.1 'echo '\''root:Te3EQeF2U!-Em_C3eBU6A&a=u2$e28*c'\'' | chpasswd'
```

better yet, it would be much simpler to just use something like this:

```
echo 'root:Te3EQeF2U!-Em_C3eBU6A&a=u2$e28*c' | ssh root@1.1.1.1 chpasswd
```